# Scale, rotate and align 2 similar models

Tags: mesh

I have 2 models, one done by photoscan and one done by 123dCatch.
Is there a way to fit the 123dcatch model inside the photoscan one?

I tried doing it by hand but my result are very shady.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about blender but a quick google search for aligning meshes brought me to [meshlab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g9Hap4rX0k).

Comment: I almost found out how to do it but still stuck at the last step http://madscientistsecretbase.com/?page_id=34 (orienting the 2 box)